# Error when execution imagemagick convert image: "delegate failed html2ps"

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, html2ps

On my server (Ubuntu 16) when converting some .jpg images instead of converting I receive error:

`` convert: delegate failed `"html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310. ``

Other .jpg-images are converted normally.

ImageMagick version 6.8.9-9, perl version 5

I tried to install html2ps (installed version only 1.0 beta7), after this operation I get this (even on simply enquiry "html2ps -v"):

```
Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at /usr/bin/html2ps line 3409.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m//DH { <-- HERE / at /usr/bin/html2ps line 3834.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\patterns{ <-- HERE .*/ at /usr/bin/html2ps line 4085.
html2ps version 1.0 beta7
```

How it is possible to correct it, that converting of these images worked?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the command you issued?

Comment: convert img1.jpg -resize 600x img2.jpg (Some images converted normally.)

Comment: That shouldn't cause `html2ps` to be run at all. I suspect you have an HTML file that has accidentally got a JPG extension and ImageMagick has tried to read the HTML. I would try running `file *jpg` to see if one of your JPEGs is actually HTML.

Comment: That is right! Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!